# How to test site speed?

Tags: performance

I'm looking to measure how fast my site is processed. Is there any software out there that can do this?

If it depends on the server, is there any way to monitor the speed from my localhost (purely CPU load?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the timer_stop() function via the WordPress 'shutdown' hook, like this:

```
// Grab the page load time upon WordPress shutdown.
function page_load_time() {

    echo '<p>Page load time: '.timer_stop(0, 5).' seconds.</p>';
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'page_load_time' );
```

Comment: So I guess I'm confused based on the above answer. What good is measuring the site load time if it does not wait until all calls to the database are complete? I'm not so much concerned as to how to get the HTML parsed as I am about the database traffic time.

Comment: The shutdown hook runs after everything has finished loading so is a good place to stop the timer.

Comment: @dgwyer is there any way to grab the page loading time when WordPress shutdown hook is not firing due to cache ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`timer_stop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop) just before `</body>`

If you want to see the execution time of each SQL query too, `define('SAVEQUERIES', true)` in your wp-config, and do a `var_dump($GLOBALS['wpdb']->queries)` in your footer.

Comment: Might be a stupid question: Since Wp is db driven, does timer_stop() stop the timer after all the calls to the server have been made?

Comment: no, it just computes the time since the timer started. that's why you should use it before the scripts ends...